# Is there a simulator for ardrone in ros kinetic

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, tum-ardrone, tum-simulator, ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am just starting out in ROS and I have installed ROS kinetic and ardrone_autonomy, but I cannot find tum_simulator or tum_ardrone branches for kinetic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251601/is-there-a-simulator-for-ardrone-in-ros-kinetic/) by [tradeA](https://answers.ros.org/users/28971/tradea/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-01-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found this repo that works for me on kinetic:

https://github.com/angelsantamaria/tum_simulator

---

Originally posted by [jannsta](https://answers.ros.org/users/26758/jannsta/) with karma: 66 on 2017-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-01-31**:
Hi, does this contain all functionalities of the original tum_simulator ?

**Comment by [vvyogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29579/vvyogi/) on 2018-03-29**:
@malharjajoo Yes it does.

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-03-29**:
Thanks @vyogi

**Comment by [Caesar84](https://answers.ros.org/users/34428/caesar84/) on 2018-04-11**:
hi there , I have ROS kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04, and already installed Hector_quadrotor. when I try to follow the above link [link text](https://github.com/angelsantamaria/tum_simulator) I faced this error message in the following comment. has anyone faced this too?

**Comment by [Caesar84](https://answers.ros.org/users/34428/caesar84/) on 2018-04-11**:
Base path: /home/mastlab/catkin_ws

Source space: /home/mastlab/catkin_ws/src

Build space: /home/mastlab/catkin_ws/build

Devel space: /home/mastlab/catkin_ws/devel

Install space: /home/mastlab/catkin_ws/install

Multiple packages found with the same name "message_to_tf":

**Comment by [Caesar84](https://answers.ros.org/users/34428/caesar84/) on 2018-04-11**:\

- hector_localization/message_to_tf
- tum_simulator/message_to_tf

**Comment by [Pramod](https://answers.ros.org/users/37950/pramod/) on 2018-10-08**:
thank you.It works :D